# Baking Glass Object with Thickness

Tags: texture-baking

Let's say you have a glass mesh with thickness. But when you bake outer surface, you know it also bakes the inner surface and others behind it too. So it is possible to ignore inner surface while baking outer surface ? Or how can you achieve that ?

Comment: What pass are you going to bake for the glass? You could assign outer surface to another material and bake it separately but it might be a workaround depending on what are you trying to do

Comment: Ok, it is a wine glass(https://prnt.sc/h65712). It has thickness (inner and outer surfaces) and wine. I arranged both faces as different material already. But when i bake outside face, it bakes wine and inner face too on it as it is glass(transparent). So i want to bake outer face without wine and inner surface on it.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean by "baking" procedure run from the [Render tab > Bake rollout](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/bake.html#bake-mode)? It's kind of unclear how and what bake pass are you baking.

Comment: No no. i am gonna bake inner surface, outer surface and wine surface on textures separately with "combined bake" under the bake tab. When i bake outer surface wine seems on baked texture too since outer surface is glass(transparent). It bakes everything which seem behind it too. I Just asked if i can bake outer surface on a texture without what seem behind it.